# CodeTo128 Function usability

Tags: t-sql, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I came up on a problem. I am using CodeTo128B function in T-SQL. The problem that i came up with if I give a value to it that has white spaces in it and then give the result to SSRS report with a sAdC128c font the barcode can not be read (the devices that reads barcodes just does not recognize it because the barcode in the image is not in tact (it has spaces in between)

I've gathered up two values for a testing reference

```
SELECT [dbo].[CodeTo128B] ('1 TEST') AS [Column]
UNION
SELECT [dbo].[CodeTo128B] ('1TEST') AS [Column]
```

[image]

The problem is that the first barcode is not recognized by the reader (Android Cell phone app **Barcode Scanner**  i think that this is because there is a space in a barcode but i can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this function why it does not recognize spaces? As i see the ASCII values are also different because of the space (Column values)

Any ideas ? Any help would be very much appreciated

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CodeTo128B] (@myString varchar(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) AS
BEGIN

-- Define the string of characters that we'll need to pull the reference of
 declare @asciiString varchar(255)
 select @asciiString = ' !"#$%&''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(195) -- 0xC3
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(196) -- 0xC4
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(197) -- 0xC5
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(198) -- 0xC6
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(199) -- 0xC7
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(200) -- 0xC8
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(201) -- 0xC9
 select @asciiString = @asciiString + char(202) -- 0xCA
 -- Define the stop and start characters
 declare @stopchar char(1)
 declare @startchar char(1)
 declare @spacechar char(1)
 select @stopchar = char(206) -- 0xCE
 select @startchar = char(204) -- 0xCC
 select @spacechar = char(194) -- 0xC2

 -- Define the final holding place of our output string
 declare @finalArray varchar(255)

 -- Define the variables that we'll need to be using
 declare @checksumTotal int
 declare @checksum int
 select @checksumTotal = 104;
 select @checksum = 0;

 -- Start building our output
 select @finalArray = @startchar

 -- Loop through our input variable and start pulling out stuff
 declare @position int
 declare @thisChar char(1)
 select @position = 1
 while @position <= len(@myString)
 begin
 select @thisChar = substring(@myString, @position, 1)
 select @checksumTotal = @checksumTotal + (@position * (ascii(@thischar)-32))
 select @finalArray = @finalArray + @thisChar
 select @position = @position + 1
 end -- We've gone past the length now

 -- Now we need to figure out and add the checksum character
 select @checksum = @checksumTotal % 103
 if @checksum = 0
 select @finalArray = @finalArray + @spacechar
 else
 -- Barcorde array assumes 0 as initial offset so we need to add 1 to checksum
 select @finalArray = @finalArray + substring(@asciiString, @checksum+1, 1)
 -- Now we append the stop character
 select @finalArray = @finalArray + @stopchar

 -- The @final Array represents the barcode encoded string
 return @finalArray

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution on my own. Just rewrote the function to recalculate when a empty value is passed and fill the empty space in the formed string

Code reference displayed bellow
Happy coding :)

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CodeTo128B]
    (
    @Barcode VARCHAR(20)
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @site_value INT;
    SET @site_value =1;

    DECLARE @v_data_to_encode varchar(4000) 
    DECLARE @check_digit_char varchar(1) 
    DECLARE @check_digit BIGINT 
    DECLARE @start_character varchar(1) 
    DECLARE @stop_character varchar(1) 
    DECLARE @current_value bigint 
    DECLARE @encoded_string varchar(1000) 
    DECLARE @weight_total BIGINT
    DECLARE @mrLen BIGINT
    SET @v_data_to_encode = UPPER(@Barcode)

    SET @start_character = CHAR(0203)
    SET @stop_character = CHAR(0206)

    SET @weight_total = ASCII(@start_character) - 100

    SET @mrLen = LEN(@v_data_to_encode)

    WHILE @site_value <= @mrLen
    BEGIN
    SET @current_value = CAST(ASCII(SUBSTRING (@v_data_to_encode, @site_value, 1)) AS BIGINT)



    if @current_value < 135 

    set @current_value = @current_value - 32 

    ELSE if @current_value >= 135 

    set @current_value = @current_value - 100 



    SET @current_value = @current_value * @site_value
    SET @weight_total = @weight_total + @current_value
    set @site_value = @site_value+1

    END
    SET @check_digit = (@weight_total % 103)

    BEGIN
    if @check_digit < 95 and @check_digit > 0 
    SET @check_digit_char = CHAR(@check_digit + 32) 
    ELSE if @check_digit >= 95 
    SET @check_digit_char = char(@check_digit + 100)
    ELSE if @check_digit = 0 
    SET @check_digit_char = char(194);

    END



    SET @encoded_string = replace(@v_data_to_encode,' ',char(194))
    return CONCAT (@start_character,@encoded_string,@check_digit_char,@stop_character)

end
```